# Custom swim lanes in fullcalendar day view

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

In fullcalendar, rather than differentiating events by colour, I'd like to show them in vertical 'swim lanes' in the day view, e.g.

```
       Calendar 1 | Calendar 2 | Calendar 3
  9am  event 1      event 2
 10am                            event 3
 11am               event 4      event 5
 12am  event 6
```

etc.

Any suggestions as to the best and quickest approach, e.g. my first thoughts are

a) styling events to give them a width and a horizontal offset, e.g. with four lanes, events would be 25% width, Calendar 2 events would be left=25% of the containing day view. Calendar headings could be added above the calendar component.

b) putting multiple calendar components on the page next to each other.

A bit of an early stage brainstorm rather than something with a specific right answer I know.

Comment: Hey, did you found an answer?

Comment: No, I'm afraid not, to be honest I can't remember why I asked this back in 2012. It seems the current fullcalendar does show overlapping items a bit better than I think it used a couple of years ago to though.